# example of infinispan domain configuration

Tags: keycloak, infinispan-9

I'm trying to deploy an infinisppan cluster (2 machines) using the domain mode. But I can't find any working example of domain.xml and host.xml config file.

This cluster would be used by keycloak as a cache server

Any luck one of you already work on this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download infinispan 9.4.14 (or any 9.4) and start the bin/domain.sh [bat] script.
That's it you have a running domain with two servers.

If you want to add a second machine you need to copy the server and start the domain script by passing "--host-config=host-slave.xml" also you need to set "jboss.domain.master.address=" with "-D" to let the process know where the domain master is.
Anothe option is to move host-slave.xml-->host.xml and edit the domain-controller discovery-options.

More information can be found here -> http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/server_guide/server_guide.html#domain_mode